# Binding ActualHeight и ActualWidth контрола в свойство ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Вроде простой вопрос, но застрял.
То-есть, есть к примеру Grid1, растянутый на отведенную для него область, как связать его актуальные размеры с свойствами во ViewModel, хотяб в одну сторону, чтоб в get`ы можно было добавить последующие обработки, связанные с изменившимся размером.

Comment: 1. Вы уверены, что размеры контрола нужны в VM? Это точно относится к логике приложения? 2. Как вы пробовали и что не получилось?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/658170/6766879

Comment: Это построение диаграммы, но мудреной как по исходным данным, так и по виду. Можно конечно использовать маштабирования, но это намного больше гемороя, чем по актуальным размерам подготовить данные.

Comment: по ссылке пару моментов интересно, может быть и получиться адаптировать, а так еще больше сложностей

Comment: Ну, второй по популярности ответ там вполне удобен, думаю. Лично я его бы и выбрал.